# Fluent Nhibernate Error while inserting records in database

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am inserting records in mysql DB by reading PDF file. There are 14000 records which are suppose to be inserted in DB. but after some 700-800 records I get an exception as "An Invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating session factory". I am using fluent      Nhibernate & My code is in asp.net.Can anyone please help me with this issue??

Comment: Are you creating the session factory multiple times ? Could you post some code snipping that explains how you are inserting these values ?

Comment: Also when describing an exception always post the full exception.  Exception.ToString() is your friend!

Comment: There is a 70% chance that if you read the messages of all InnerExceptions recursively, you will discover the problem.

Comment: Hello All, Actual cause is not what I have mentioned above. I am sorry for that. I got to know that I am getting above error because of Out of memory exception.

Comment: @bernhardrusch Yes Sir I am creating it multiple times..I think it is primary cause for OOM exception..

Comment: @Abhijit: normally you would create one Session object and use this for all of your inserts. You would be using something like using (var session = HowEveryouGetYourSession()). I'd use a transaction to handle the import and commit it after importing the data from one patient. Maybe this helps your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= iPages; i++)  // ipages value is 2213
        {
            string strPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfRdr, i);
            strPageText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strPageText)));

            string[] strRows = strPageText.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            string strName = string.Empty;
            string[] strNames;
            string strStatus = string.Empty;
            string EmailAddress = string.Empty;
            int rowCount = 1;
            int iPtRowCnt = 0;
            bool caseFiveFlag = false;


            Patient objPt = new Patient();
            objPt.PatientContact = new PatientContact();

            foreach (string strRowText in strRows)
            {
               // here I am inserting records by parsing .pdf file 
               // my pdf file is 5mb
            }
```